# Smooth animation for newly added data points with flot

Tags: javascript, animation, flot

I need to animate a real time graph with flot so that each new data point will transition smooth into the data set etc.

I've made a plunker with the basic flow:
http://plnkr.co/edit/oPahmS?p=preview

But I would like to make it more like highcharts

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update

Does anyone know a plugin or a way to do this with flot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe either of the flot animation plugins provide this ability.  Instead, it can be done with a little bit of jquery [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) magic.

```
addPointAnimate = function(){
    var series = somePlot.getData()[0]; // first series
    var lastX = series.data[series.data.length-1][0]; // last x value
    var opts = somePlot.getOptions();
    opts.xaxes[0].max += 1; // adjust xaxis to make room for new point
    somePlot.setupGrid();
    $('#placeholder').animate( { 1:1 }, {
         duration: 1000,
         step: function ( now, fx ) {
             series.data.push([lastX+fx.pos, Math.sin(lastX+fx.pos)]); // for each step of animation, push on an intermediate value
             somePlot.setData( [series] );
             somePlot.draw(); // redraw with intermediate value
         }
   });
   return true;
}
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/9MEVk/).

Comment: Excellent answer; nice animation from a compact little block of code.